# What is the fastest way to determine if a URL exists in PHP?

Tags: php, url

I need to create a function that returns if a URL is reachable or valid.

I am currently using something like the following to determine a valid url:

```
static public function urlExists($url)
{
    $fp = @fopen($url, 'r');

    if($fp)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

It seems like there would be something faster, maybe something that just fetched the page header or something.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could check [http status code](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html).

Here is a code you could use to check that an url returns 2xx or 3xx http code to ensure the url works.

```
<?php

$url = "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1122845";

function urlOK($url)
{

    $url_data = parse_url ($url);
    if (!$url_data) return FALSE;

   $errno="";
   $errstr="";
   $fp=0;

   $fp=fsockopen($url_data['host'],80,$errno,$errstr,30);

   if($fp===0) return FALSE;
   $path ='';
   if  (isset( $url_data['path'])) $path .=  $url_data['path'];
   if  (isset( $url_data['query'])) $path .=  '?' .$url_data['query'];

   $out="GET /$path HTTP/1.1\r\n";
   $out.="Host: {$url_data['host']}\r\n";
   $out.="Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";

   fwrite($fp,$out);
   $content=fgets($fp);
   $code=trim(substr($content,9,4)); //get http code
   fclose($fp);
   // if http code is 2xx or 3xx url should work
   return  ($code[0] == 2 || $code[0] == 3) ? TRUE : FALSE;
}

echo $url;
if (urlOK($url)) echo " is a working URL";
    else echo " is a bad URL";
?>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 12):

You can use curl as follows:

```
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true); // set to HEAD request
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // don't output the response
curl_exec($ch);
$valid = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE) == 200;
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Also check for 2xx and 3xx because it could be 301 Moved Permanently or another http code that means the url works.

Answer (score 5):

You'll likely be limited to sending some kind of HTTP request.  Then you can check HTTP status codes.

Be sure to send only a "HEAD" request, which doesn't pull back all the content.  That ought to be sufficient and lightweight enough.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this because curl doesn't work for me and the target server was sending 403 for HEAD requests.
Here wget will attempt to download the first 24 bytes of a file.

```
private function urlExists($url):bool
{
    $command = 'wget '.$url.' -t 1 --header="Range: bytes=0-24" -q --directory-prefix "'.$this->tempDir.'"';
    $res = [];
    $resultCode = 1000; //any int other than 0
    exec($command, $res, $resultCode);
    return $resultCode === 0;
}
```