# Don't check the domain name only

Tags: php, phpbb

Soooo it's me again with this function..

I have the function working.

```
function http_file_exists($url)
{
  $f = @fopen($url,"r");
  if($f)
  {
    fclose($f);
  return true;
  }
return false;
}
```

And this is the usage :

```
if ($submit || $preview || $refresh)
{
 $post_data['your_url'] = "http://www.google.com/this"; //remove the equals and url value if using in real post
  $your_url = $post_data['your_url'];
  $your_url_exists = (isset($your_url)) ? true : false;
  $your_url = preg_replace(array('#&\#46;#','#&\#58;#','/\[(.*?)\]/'), array('.',':',''), $your_url);

  if ($your_url_exists && http_file_exists($your_url) == true)
  {
    trigger_error('exists!');
  }
```

How do I let it check the whole url and not the domain name only ? for example http://www.google.com/this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

url tested is http://www.google.com/abadurltotest

source of code below = [What is the fastest way to determine if a URL exists in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1122845/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-determine-if-a-url-exists-in-php)

```
function http_file_exists($url) 
{
  //$url = preg_replace(array('#&\#46;#','#&\#58;#','/\[(.*?)\]/'), array('.',':',''), $url); 
$url_data = parse_url ($url);
    if (!$url_data) return FALSE;

   $errno="";
   $errstr="";
   $fp=0;

   $fp=fsockopen($url_data['host'],80,$errno,$errstr,30);

   if($fp===0) return FALSE;
   $path ='';
   if  (isset( $url_data['path'])) $path .=  $url_data['path'];
   if  (isset( $url_data['query'])) $path .=  '?' .$url_data['query'];

   $out="GET /$path HTTP/1.1\r\n";
   $out.="Host: {$url_data['host']}\r\n";
   $out.="Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";

   fwrite($fp,$out);
   $content=fgets($fp);
   $code=trim(substr($content,9,4)); //get http code
   fclose($fp);
   // if http code is 2xx or 3xx url should work
   return  ($code[0] == 2 || $code[0] == 3) ? TRUE : FALSE;
}
```

add the top code to functions_posting.php replacing previous function

```
if ($submit || $preview || $refresh)
{
 $post_data['your_url'] = " http://www.google.com/abadurltotest"; 
  $your_url = $post_data['your_url'];
  $your_url_exists = (request_var($your_url, '')) ? true : false;
  $your_url = preg_replace(array('#&\#46;#','#&\#58;#','/\[(.*?)\]/'), array('.',':',''), $your_url);

  if ($your_url_exists === true && http_file_exists($your_url) === false)
  {
    trigger_error('A bad url was entered, Please push the browser back button and try again.');
  }
```

Comment: It's not triggering the error at all even if I post that url http://www.google.com/abadurltotest

Comment: Because it only triggers on a good url not a bad url.


`if ($your_url_exists && http_file_exists($your_url) === false)
  {
    trigger_error('Sorry, that was a bad url entered, please press the back button and try again with a valid url!');
  }`

Comment: Nope,still the same. don't know what's wrong. the one I posted first was working a bit better. I'll look into it :\

Answer (score 0):

Use curl and check the HTTP status code. if it's not 200 - most likely the url doesn't exist or inaccessible.

also note that

```
$your_url_exists = (isset($your_url)) ? true : false;
```

makes no sense. It seems you want

```
$your_url_exists = (bool)$your_url;
```

or just check `$your_url` instead of `$your_url_exists`

Comment: Something seems to be so wrong.
It doesn't matter what the link is,it's enough to try and post http://www. - then it shows that the link exists no matter what comes next.

Comment: I hope you can help me out..!