# How to use file_get_contents if I don't have protocol information about website

Tags: php, html

The code I am using is:

```
$url = "example.com";
$code =  file_get_contents("http://www.".$url);
if (!$code) {
    $code =  file_get_contents("https://www.".$url);
}
```

I don't know whether each URL starts with `http` or `https`. I have 1,000 URLs saved in my database. Any suggestions?

Comment: You have to use trial and error since your data is _not_ URLs, but only strings that might be interpreted as host names.

Comment: You can try both, if you don't find the `https` resource you can fallback to `http`. Or vice versa.

Comment: You can loop on these urls and with if condition you can know which one is working

Comment: @Federkun Can you please help me in if else statement. Because when i try it gives error and page stop execution.

Comment: What help do you need? What have you tried? Edit your question with the code

Comment: Do you know for sure that every URL will include the www subdomain?

Comment: @DaveP No, I don't know.

Comment: I only have data which is in the form of example.com, site.com, example2.com

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1122845/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-determine-if-a-url-exists-in-php) is somewhat relevant. Given that your database is rather incomplete in that the URLs aren't fully qualified, I would be inclined to write a short routine to update the database for future use.

```
<?php
$url = 'example.com';
$variations[] = 'http://'.$url;
$variations[] = 'https://'.$url;
$variations[] = 'http://www.'.$url;
$variations[] = 'https://www'.$url;
foreach($variations as $v){
  // Check variation with function from answer linked above
  if(urlOK($v)){
    // code to update database row
    // or if you don't want to do that
    $code =  file_get_contents($v);
  }
}
```